# SVG possible to be transparent fill?

Tags: css, svg, fill

I have a problem with an SVG with a fill currently at #ffffff. The problem is, this is covering the images I have at the bottom. I want this to be transparent. There are other pages that look good and transparent.

How can I fix this?

Actually, I also have a problem with how the images repeat itself behind instead of being one single image.

The website is here: http://canadawidecontractors.com/new/heating-and-cooling-services/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you are referring to.

If you mean you want the triangular separator to cover the (currently) grey placeholder image, then you need to move it up.

At the moment the separator is sitting between the grey image area and the blue area.  Your "white" triangle is not actually white.  It's transparent.  But is showing the white background underneath.

What you could do is move the separator up, for example with `margin-top: -100px`.

```
<div class="box-container wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1437615582345" style="
    margin-top: -100px;">
```

I'm using a style attribute here for demo purposes. You should actually put it in your stylesheet of course.

Comment: Hi I have fixed it already yesterday I had no clue how the plugin actually worked.prior It allowed me to set a -100px margin at the bottom of the seperator to bring up the triangle. Thank you though, I should have updated my post.